# dynamic Procedure, remove last string chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have  a parameter that dynamically generates UNION ALL
depends on the input.

```
    SELECT @CMD +=N'

 SET NOCOUNT ON;     
 SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=4
           THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
           END) RequiredaQueue

             ,COUNT(DISTINCT RFRD.LeadDocumentID) AS Repeat,CONCAT('''+RF+''' ,'' '') AS RiskFactorID
        FROM FCT.RiskMng_fact_RiskFactorResultDetails AS RFRD


    UNION ALL

 SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=4
           THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
           END) RequiredaQueue

         ,COUNT(DISTINCT RFRD.LeadDocumentID)AS Repeat,CONCAT('''+RF+''' ,''*'')  AS RiskFactorID
        FROM FCT.RiskMng_fact_RiskFactorResultDetails AS RFRD'
        --------------
            FROM #cte RF    
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @CMD
```

at the end i want to connect them all into one long UNION, so i added a UNION ALL in the end:

```
          SELECT @CMD +=N'

 SET NOCOUNT ON;     
 SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=4
           THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
           END) RequiredaQueue

             ,COUNT(DISTINCT RFRD.LeadDocumentID) AS Repeat,CONCAT('''+RF+''' ,'' '') AS RiskFactorID
        FROM FCT.RiskMng_fact_RiskFactorResultDetails AS RFRD


    UNION ALL

 SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN RFRD.QueuTypeID=4
           THEN RFRD.QueuTypeID
           END) RequiredaQueue

         ,COUNT(DISTINCT RFRD.LeadDocumentID)AS Repeat,CONCAT('''+RF+''' ,''*'')  AS RiskFactorID
        FROM FCT.RiskMng_fact_RiskFactorResultDetails AS RFRD'
        --------------
        +' UNION ALL '  <-----------------------


FROM #cte RF    
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @CMD
```

after it runs, the last UNION ALL is Needless,
and i get errors:

```
            ON  OU.ID = RFRD.Entity_OrganizationUnitID
            INNER JOIN #Entity_OrganizationUnitTypeIDs OUT
                ON  OUT.ID = RFRD.Entity_OrganizationUnitTypeID         

        WHERE   RFRD.EntityTypeID = 1055
        and RFRD.riskfactorid IN(6249,6102)
             AND RFRD1.ID IS NULL  
              UNION ALL
```

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 118

can anyone suggest how can i remove only the last UNION ALL?
maybe i should not add a UNION AL at the end? 
Thanks

Comment: just remove UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

At the end you need to remove it by

```
set @CMD = substring(@CMD,1,len(@CMD)-9)
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @CMD
```

Answer (score 0):

The UNION ALL command takes two parameters, the table before and the table after the UNION ALL command.

So it should allways have the form

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT col3 as col1,col4 as col2 FROM B
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are concatenating your `SELECT` statements, why not check to see if the existing string is empty, and add the `UNION ALL` then only if it is required, for example:

```
SELECT @CMD = @CMD + 
       CASE WHEN @CMD = '' THEN '' ELSE ' UNION ALL ' END + 
       'SELECT ... '
```

Then you won't be in the situation where you'll have to strip anything back out again.